# Updating dictionaries without data loss

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.4

If I have two dictionaries that looks like this:

```
a = {"fruit":["orange", "lemon"], "vegetable":["carrot", "tomato"]}
b = {"fruit":["banana", "lime"]}
```

Is there a way I can update dictionary 'a' so that I don't overwrite the previous data, but simply append it so that my result would look like this?

```
a = {"fruit":["orange", "lemon", "banana", "lime"], "vegetable": ["carrot", "tomato"]}
```

I know there is something similar , but unfortunately it rewrites the values, which is not what I am looking to do:

```
a.update(b)
#returns a dictionary like the following {"fruit":["banana", "lime"], "vegetable":["carrot","tomato"]}, again, not what I want.
```

Answer (score 3):

No way without a loop:

```
for k, v in b.items():
    a[k].extend(v)
```

This assumes that `a[k]` actually exists . . . If you want to add it in the case where it is missing:

```
for k, v in b.items():
    try:
        a[k].extend(v)
    except KeyError:
        a[k] = v
```

Comment: That's rather unfortunate

Comment: @sudobangbang -- It's really not that much code :-)

Comment: Im more worried about effeciency

Comment: `a.setdefault(k, []).extend(v)`

Comment: @chepner -- Yep, or even using a `defaultdict` might be an option.

Comment: @sudobangbang Don't worry about efficiency unless you know it's an issue. Implement, profile, then optimize the bottlenecks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), but you have to iterate over the items.

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(list)
```

You could also define a helper method (but be careful not to call it with a normal dict, some type check may be appropriate):

```
def update(a,b):
    for k, v in b.items():
        a[k].extend(v)
```

The other option is to extend dict and override the update method to do it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a simple while loop:

```
accesos = {'carlos pinto': 23849284}

while True:
    nueva_persona = input("Nombre?: ")
    nueva_clave = input("Clave?: ")

    accesos[nueva_persona] = nueva_clave
    print(accesos)
```